# HorizontalScrollView transparent

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

With HorizontalScrollView, how can I make the background not transparent? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in xml:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

or in java class:

```
yourView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: just found out objects on the view including spinner and button, will automatically become transparent in android 4.3